# Jqgrid Get postData

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php

I would like to export only the data from jqgrid.

So basically I already have a bound grid with data and I want to get the data as json string so I can call `BindGridModel(data)` later on and bind the data without going back to the server only from client side.

how can I get data as json string so later on I can give it to the grid as data?

this is my grid configuration:

```
function BindGridModel(data) {
    $('#jqgInventory').jqGrid({
        autowidth: true,
        caption: 'Inventory',
        datatype: 'json',
        forceFit: true,
        gridview: true,
        height: 500,
        hidegrid: false,
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadui: 'disable',
        pager: '#pager',
        mtype: 'post',
        rowNum: 25,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        url: '/MCI/Inventory/Inventory/GetIndexGridData',
        viewrecords: true,
        postData: {
            modelView: JSON.stringify(model),
            __RequestVerificationToken: $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        beforeRequest: function() {
            $('#gridScript').block();
        },
        beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
            return false;
        },
        gridComplete: function() {
            $('#lblVehicleCount').html($('#jqgInventory').getGridParam('records'));
            $('#gridScript').unblock();
            Inventory.modifyGridCellClick();
        },
        colModel: [
            {
            align: 'center',
            name: 'Select',
            label: 'SEL',
            title: true,
            width: 20,
            index: 'Select'},
        {
            align: 'left',
            name: 'Photo',
            hidden: false,
            label: 'PHOTO',
            stype: 'text',
            sortable: false,
            sorttype: 'text',
            title: true,
            width: 100,
            index: 'Photo'},
        {
            align: 'left',
            name: 'Information',
            hidden: false,
            label: 'INFO',
            stype: 'text',
            sortable: false,
            sorttype: 'text',
            title: true,
            width: 100,
            index: 'Information'},
        {
            align: 'right',
            name: 'Price',
            hidden: false,
            label: 'PRICE',
            stype: 'text',
            sortable: true,
            sorttype: function(cellValue) {
                return CustomGridSortByIntegerAsString(cellValue);
            },
            title: true,
            width: 50,
            index: 'Price'},
        {
            align: 'right',
            name: 'Mileage',
            hidden: false,
            label: 'MILEAGE',
            stype: 'text',
            sortable: true,
            sorttype: function(cellValue) {
                return CustomGridSortByIntegerAsString(cellValue);
            },
            title: true,
            width: 25,
            index: 'Mileage'},
        {
            align: 'right',
            name: 'Age',
            hidden: false,
            label: 'AGE',
            stype: 'text',
            sortable: true,
            sorttype: function(cellValue) {
                return CustomGridSortByIntegerAsString(cellValue);
            },
            title: true,
            width: 50,
            index: 'Age'},
        {
            name: 'VehicleKey',
            hidden: true,
            label: 'VEHICLEKEY',
            width: 50,
            index: 'VehicleKey'}
        ],
        data: data
    });
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `data` parameter you should use `datatype: 'local'` and not `datatype: 'json'`. Moreover it's unclear whether you want to export *one page* of data which are currently displayed or you want to export all data. Moreover you wrote about "to get the data as json string" which is a little strange. Typically one get data as *object* (array of items which represent the data from rows of the grid) and convert it to JSON in some cases only if it's needed to sent to the server.

Comment: Don't worry about data parameter because I am building the grid script dynamically so some pages will load the data at once and some of them will do a server post to get the data. I want to export the data with column names so I can add some more data to it and bind it back, I am doing something like get the first 25 records then when u click on next page I store this 25 records somewhere and on my way back after grabbing the next 25 I want to add them to the first 25 and display the 50 records, I am trying to see if there is a way of doing it with built- in pager.

Answer (score 0):

In the [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event you have access to the data that was bound to the grid, and can JSON stringify it. I typically set that to a Jquery data property so that I have access to it outside of the event.

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
    $('#gridid').data('jqdata', data);//JSON stringify the data 1st if you need to
},
```

You can then access that data later via:

```
$('#gridid').data('jqdata');
```

Comment: great that what I needed, but now how to modify this data and reload the gird?

Comment: Modifying the data is just like modifying any other Jquery object. After modification you would just rebind that object to the grid, set it in local mode, and call the $('#gridid').trigger('reloadGrid'); to refresh. If you need a more details explanation I suggest starting a new question.